# Is it possible to combine a line and stacked bar chart in grafana v9.x

Tags: grafana

I have a dual y-axis time series chart with some data displayed as bars and some as lines. I would like to stack the bar data but when I set stack ON for the panel it also tries to stack the line data which results in a mess.

Answer (score 0):

In case it's useful for somebody - this can be done by setting the stacking option on individual series overrides